# Django admin - detect changed fields in inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it posiible to detect what fields were changed while saving Inlines? I use save_formset method, but have no idea how to detect changed fields.
I need it to detect if image is cleared in admin.

Comment: Why do you need to detect it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the existing entry from the database and then comparing that with the entry that you are about to save is a pretty easy way to achieve this.

```
existing_entry = Model.objects.get(pk=entry_to_save.pk)
if existing_entry.image != entry_to_save.image:
    # Your image has been modified
entry_to_save.save()
```